# Promise.all not working at expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I expected the Promise.all code to return

```
{ constant: 'x1' }
{ constant: 'x2' }
{ constant: 'x3' }
```

but instead I have this:

```
{ constant: 'x1' }
{ constant: 'x12' }
{ constant: 'x123' }
```

Why would this happen? I can not seem to see where 'constant' is accumulating.

This is a simplified view - I actually updated/create a document in "testFN"

thanks

```
function testFN(blob, array, iter){
    var newBlob = blob;
    newBlob.constant = blob.constant+array.num
    console.log(newBlob);
    return products.findOneAndUpdate ....   
}

exports.updateProductId = function(req, res) {

    var blob = {"constant":"x"};
    var arr = { key1:{num: "1"}, key2:{num: "2"}, key3:{num: "3"}};
    var fnArr = [];

    Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(key, i) {
       fnArr.push(testFN(blob, arr[key], i));
    });

    return Promise.all(fnArr)
    .then(function(success){
        console.log(success);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })

})
```

Comment: Why are you using `Promise.all()` with a static array of values?  That is not what it is for or what is useful for.  You pass `Promise.all()` an array of promises.  It then monitors all those promises and tells you when they are all done.  You're just passing it an array of values which are already filled in so it's just going to give you back that same array.

Comment: Do you realize that when you construct `fnArr`, you're calling `testFn()` immediately and pushing the return value into `fnArr` so when you call `Promise.all()`, you're passing it an array that is already filled in with all the values.

Comment: you are returning a promise that will resolve to `undefined` - also, your array passed to Promise.all is an array of `undefined` - and there's no asynchrony in the code whatsoever (until you made it so with Promise.all)

Comment: The `Promise.all()` part of your code has nothing to do with anything.  All your code has already run before you call `Promise.all()`.  So, the title of the question is very misguided.  You appear to think that `Promise.all()` does something with your code/data that it does not do.  In fact, all your `console.log()` statements except the success one has already run before you even call `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-primitives are passed by *reference* - you can think of any variable that represents an object as a reference to a *memory location*. So, in `testFN`:

```
function testFN(blob, array, iter){
  var newBlob = blob;
  newBlob.constant = blob.constant+array.num
```

`newBlob` points to the same place in memory as the `blob` parameter, so when you change `newBlob.constant`, you change the original `blob.constant` as well (since they're the same object). You can fix it by assigning a *true* copy of `blob` to `newBlob`:

```js
function testFN(blob, array, iter){
  var newBlob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blob));
  newBlob.constant = blob.constant + array.num;
  console.log(newBlob);
  return newBlob;
}
var blob = {"constant":"x"};
var arr = { key1:{num: "1"}, key2:{num: "2"}, key3:{num: "3"}};
var fnArr = [];

Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(key, i) {
  fnArr.push(testFN(blob, arr[key], i));
});

Promise.all(fnArr)
  .then(function(success){
  console.log(success);
})
  .catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

This has nothing to do with `Promise.all`. None of this code is asynchronous anyway.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

Promise.all can work with array of Promises change you function "testFN" to return Promise.

```
function testFN(blob, array, iter){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var newBlob = blob;
       newBlob.constant = blob.constant+array.num;
       console.log(newBlob);
       resolve();
    });
}
```

But you might what to see if you need Promise.all in this case at all. Bcause you do not have any Async operation here

Comment: Why would you introduce asynchrony where there is no need?

Comment: No sure why this is down-voted, the question is about why Promise.all is not working and the reason is clearly answered here. Also added a note to rethink if Promise.all is required at all?

Comment: Your answer does not remotely address the problem OP was having. Whether `testFN` returns a Promise or not is completely irrelevant because all the code in `testFN` is synchronous.